# Cycles + Glass + Light, Preview different than render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, light

[image: My setup so far]Anyone knows why the preview (left bottom) looks different than the render (bottom right)?

What i tried to achieve is something like [that](https://www.eibmarkt.com/Files/Bild2/Werma-826_300_00-Warnleuchte.JPG)

i dont know what is going on?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are one or more objects, which are visible in the viewport, but hidden in the render.

Tick the camera symbol for all objects, which are supposed to be rendered.

[image: render visibility]

If you want to clear all render restriction, go to the *3D Viewport*, and press <kbd>W</kbd> in Object mode and choose **Clear All Restrict Render**.

Comment: ah thats what i noticed exat the moment when i posted this.. thanks so much!